# Adding strings in function to generate random sentences and paragraphs php

Tags: php

I have a file named `test.txt` and I want to randomly generate articles from sentences in file. And add random number of paragraphs.

> For example content of test.txt file is:
>
> Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3. Sentence 4. Sentence 5? Sentence
>   6! Sentence 7.

The output should be

Paragraph1
Sentence 1. Sentence 7 Sentence5?

Paragraph2
Sentence 3. Sentence2. Sentence7? Sentence2.

Next I want output to put in database like that :

```
$ins = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO posty SET title='$title', content='$content'");
```

I got code like that but something is wrong:

```
<?php
    $liczbaparagrafow = rand(3, 10);
    $losowaliczba = rand(7, 20);

    function powtarzacz($liczbawykonan){
        while($zmienna < $liczbawykonan) // warunek kontynuacji pętli
        {
            $f_contents = file("test.txt");
            $line = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
            $liczbawykonan++;
            return $line;
            echo $line;
            $zmienna++;
        }         
    }

    $test = powtarzacz($losowaliczba);
    echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change testy.txt to text.txt in $f_contents = file("testy.txt"); . I hope there is a typo error in your code.

Comment: Its just misspell. But not helped. ty anyway